# How to validate uniquness across models in MongoDB with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In my rails app, I use MongoDB. I have 4 models including the admin. All the entities have an email address. I need to make validation to make sure that the email is unique for all the models.

Is there a simpler/better way to do that other than searching for the email in every model?

like

```rb
 def email_uniquness_across_models(email)
    User.where(email: email).exists? ||
      Admin.where(email: email).exists? ||
      Transporter.where(email: email).exists? ||
      Company.where(email: email).exists?
  end
```

Comment: In MongoDB the equivilent to a join would be [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is the equivilent to the SQL EXIST keyword. But I'm not even sure its possible.

Comment: You might want to try either asking a separate question or rephrasing the question as a MongoDB question as their are far more experts on the database itself then experts at Mongoid.

Comment: An inheritance model with common fields from all 4 models can be made and validation can be checked on that.
Also, you don't need to write where query as the key is unique, so just 
User.find_by(email: email).present? || Admin.find_by(email: email).present? should do the trick.

Comment: In terms of code complexity, the `lookup` version is much worse than invoking `exists?` once per model as you currently have.

Comment: It depends on how important this uniqueness is... because if it crucial you will need to implement a mutex.

Comment: @UdiCohen No it's not crucial. I just want a simpler way to validate email uniqueness across models. I am also interested to know more about the mutex approach.

Comment: @kerolloz Ruby have a simple [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Mutex.html) implemented to support shared data lock between threads. You can inherit from this class to implement a distributed mutex implementation that uses monodb's [find_one_and_update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) (with `upsert: true`) which can give you a DB lock by a key of your choosing.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are set on keeping the models as they are, and have to keep the uniqness of emails between 4 collection, I would create an Email model in its own collection with a unique index defined on the email field:

```rb
class Email
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email, type: String
  index({email: 1}, {unique: true})
end
```

This way all you have to do is to try and create that Email model. If you succeed you can go ahead and create the specific model you want, knowing that the email is unique across all models. (this suggestion is similar to what @huzaifa-saifuddin suggested, but without combining all the models into one collection)

Then the uniqueness method definition would have a single call to the DB and would look like this:

```rb
def email_uniquness_across_models(email)
  Email.create(email: email)
  true
rescue
  false
end
```

IMHO it is better to have one call to the DB that ensure uniqueness than 4 calls that will ensure uniqueness **most** of the times.

This implementation will ensure the uniqueness but you will also have to handle failures - meaning handle the case where the subsequent model creation failed and you now need to remove the Email document so the specific email will be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional model & collection whose job is to store the email addresses, and add a unique index there. First create a document in this collection when creating a new user/admin/transporter/company, if that succeeded use the same email address in one of the other models.